# OpenNN returns scaled output values

Tags: c++, neural-network

I have an issue with OpenNN, and unfortunately the documentation is lacking quite a bit.

I am trying with some randomly generated data to create a Neural Network, and the results I get from the code is scaled (I assume that this is the issue), but I don't see an option to turn off the scaling without getting errors, and I can't figure out how to scale the output.

Below is my code to create the NN:

```
struct DataHold {
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> dataPoints;
        double learnValueGlucose;
        double learnValueHarn;
        double learnValueCholesterin;
        std::string debugString;
    };

void MachLearning::CreateNNModel(std::vector<MachLearning::DataHold>& input, std::string fileName, std::vector<int>& indices) {
    if(input.size() == 0) {
        throw;
    }

    int size = 0;

    for(int index = 0; index < indices.size(); ++index) {
        size += input.at(0).dataPoints.at(indices.at(index)).size();
    }

    OpenNN::DataSet data_set(input.size(), size, 1);
    OpenNN::Matrix<double> dataMatrix(input.size(), size + 1);
    OpenNN::Vector<double> dataVector;

    dataVector.resize(size + 1);

    for(unsigned int index = 0; index < input.size(); ++index) {
        unsigned int runIndex = 0;
        for(unsigned int runningIndex = 0; runningIndex < indices.size(); ++runningIndex) {
            for(unsigned int thisIndex = 0; runIndex < dataVector.size() - 1 && thisIndex < input.at(index).dataPoints.at(indices.at(runningIndex)).size(); ++runIndex, ++thisIndex) {
                dataVector.at(runIndex) = input.at(index).dataPoints.at(indices.at(runningIndex)).at(thisIndex);
            }
            dataVector.at(dataVector.size() - 1) = input.at(index).learnValueGlucose;
            dataMatrix.set_row(index, dataVector);
        }
    }

    data_set.set_data(dataMatrix);

    OpenNN::VariablesInformation* variables_information_pointer = data_set.get_variables_information_pointer();

    for(unsigned int index = 0; index < size; ++index) {
        variables_information_pointer->set_name(index, std::string(std::string("frequency").append(std::to_string(index))));
        variables_information_pointer->set_units(index, "hertzs");
        variables_information_pointer->set_description(index, "No Text");
    }

    const OpenNN::Vector<OpenNN::Vector<std::string> > inputs_targets_information = variables_information_pointer->arrange_inputs_targets_information();
    const OpenNN::Vector< OpenNN::Vector<double> > inputs_targets_statistics = data_set.scale_inputs_targets();

    OpenNN::InstancesInformation* instances_information_pointer = data_set.get_instances_information_pointer();
    instances_information_pointer->split_random_indices();

    const unsigned int inputs_number = variables_information_pointer->count_inputs_number();
    const unsigned int hidden_perceptrons_number = 9;
    const unsigned int outputs_number = variables_information_pointer->count_targets_number();
    delete neural_network;

    neural_network = new OpenNN::NeuralNetwork(inputs_number, hidden_perceptrons_number, outputs_number);
    neural_network->set_inputs_outputs_information(inputs_targets_information);
    neural_network->set_inputs_outputs_statistics(inputs_targets_statistics);
    neural_network->set_scaling_unscaling_layers_flag(true);

    OpenNN::PerformanceFunctional performance_functional(neural_network, &data_set);

    OpenNN::TrainingStrategy training_strategy(&performance_functional);

    OpenNN::QuasiNewtonMethod* quasi_Newton_method_pointer = new OpenNN::QuasiNewtonMethod( &performance_functional );
    quasi_Newton_method_pointer->set_minimum_performance_increase( 1.0e-6 );
    quasi_Newton_method_pointer->set_reserve_evaluation_history( true );
    training_strategy.set_main_training_algorithm_pointer(quasi_Newton_method_pointer);
    OpenNN::TrainingStrategy::Results training_strategy_results = training_strategy.perform_training();

    neural_network->set_inputs_scaling_outputs_unscaling_methods("MinimumMaximum");
    neural_network->set_scaling_unscaling_layers_flag(true);

    OpenNN::TestingAnalysis testing_analysis(neural_network, &data_set);
    OpenNN::FunctionRegressionTesting* function_regression_testing_pointer = testing_analysis.get_function_regression_testing_pointer();

    OpenNN::FunctionRegressionTesting::LinearRegressionAnalysisResults linear_regression_analysis_results = function_regression_testing_pointer->perform_linear_regression_analysis();

    neural_network->save("neural_network.xml");
    neural_network->save_expression("expression.txt");

    performance_functional.save("performance_functional.xml");

    training_strategy.save("training_strategy.xml");

    training_strategy_results.save("training_strategy_results.dat");
    linear_regression_analysis_results.save("linear_regression_analysis_results.dat");

    return;
}
```

The code that calculates the output:

```
double MachLearning::GetNNValue(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& input, std::vector<int>& indices) {
    OpenNN::Vector<double> dataVector;
    int size = 0;
    for(int index = 0; index < indices.size(); ++index) {
        size += input.at(indices.at(index)).size();
    }

    dataVector.resize(size);

    int runIndex = 0;
    for(unsigned int index = 0; index < indices.size(); ++index) {
        for(unsigned int smallIndex = 0; smallIndex < input.at(indices.at(index)).size(); ++smallIndex, ++runIndex) {
            dataVector.at(runIndex) = input.at(indices.at(index)).at(smallIndex);
        }
    }

    std::vector<double> test;
    test = neural_network->calculate_outputs(dataVector);
    return test.at(0);
}
```

I have tested this with some randomly generated vectors, and the correlation between what it should be, and what the NN calculates is at 0.999(..), but its scaled to something like -1 to 1 or so (I have had 1.2 already as result, guess the inputs were just bigger randomed then).

Anyone know how the OpenNN interface works exactly? I tried a bit with the scaling_unscaling flag, but that had no impact at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using an old version of OpenNN. You can download the latest version from SourceForge: [https://sourceforge.net/projects/opennn](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opennn/)

Regarding the scaling/unscaling stuff, you can disable that by doing:

```
scaling_layer.set_scaling_method(NoScaling);

unscaling_layer.set_unscaling_method(NoUnscaling);
```